# Random redirect like an A/B test

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, ab-testing

I want to test a part of my website with an A/B test.
For this I want to redirect users to one of two different URLs randomly, by clicking a button.

The user is on e.g. /register and now I want to randomly sent him to /success-v1 or /success-v2 by clicking the "register now" button on /register

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="button" id="testbutton">
  Go for it
</div>
```

Here the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testbutton').click(function(){
        if(Math.random() > 0.5) { 
            window.location.href = "http://host/versionA";
            } else {
            window.location.href = "http://host/versionB"; 
            }
    });
});
```

But somehow, it's not working :/

Thank you!

Comment: Put the URLs in to an array then choose one of those items randomly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array, then use `window.location.assign()` to redirect

Comment: hey ok, sounds great, but my JS skills are pretty low. I have no idea, how to combine. Could you maybe give me a quick example, how this could look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be in a parent page:

```
if(Math.random() > 0.5) { 
    window.location.href = "http://host/versionA"; 
} else {
    window.location.href = "http://host/versionB"; 
}
```

Comment: ah maybe you got me wrong. The user is on e.g. /register and now I want to randomly sent him to /success-v1 or /success-v2 by clicking the "register now" button on /register

Comment: Hey, I created this fiddle by trying to connect your code with click code, but it doesn't work. What is wrong? Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maxbln/kcok4yru/1/

Comment: I believe jsfiddle doesn't allow redirections, I've tested it locally and it works

Comment: Oh perfect, my fault. Thank you, I will test it!